Polynomial roots question.
I found this question in the web:
Find the number of real roots, if $1/(x+p)  + 1/(x+q)  + 1/(x+r)  = 3/x$. I can do it till a quadratic form: $(p+q+r)x²+(pq+qr+rp)x+3pqr=0$. But then the determinant remains such that I can't express it as a square. Did I miss something?

You've shown that there are at most 2 roots (real otherwise). $\quad$ All that you need is for the discriminant to be non-negative, it doesn't have to be a nice square. $\quad$ Hint: (Highlight to reveal text) $ \color{white} {\text{Draw the graph to show that there exist 2 real roots.}}$.

Note: Please check your arithmetic. If you spot no errors, please write out your sequence of steps to arrive at the expression.

Is any information given or assumed about $p$, $q$ and $r$?

Unfortunately there was nothing else given
